# Doctrine QueryBuilder need change ON condition for leftJoin

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have native sql query with left join when have on with or condition, how to represent it in query builder ?

```
 $query = "  SELECT  te.id
            FROM    task_executions AS te
            INNER JOIN tasks AS t ON t.id = te.task_id
            LEFT JOIN cost_objects AS co ON co.id = t.cost_object_id
            LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers AS com ON com.cost_object_id = co.id OR com.cost_object_id = co.parent_id
```

and I need represent it in query builder. But in `User` entity I have ManyToMany relation, without separate table and when I try left join `WITH` condition this is not same what I need. I need change relation for `ON`

```
LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers AS com ON com.cost_object_id = co.id OR com.cost_object_id = co.parent_id
```

User entity

```
class User
{
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CostObject", mappedBy="users")
 */
private $costObjects;
}
```

CostObject entity

```
class CostObject
{
    /**
 * @var CostObject
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CostObject", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 */
private $parent;

    /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="costObjects")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="cost_object_managers",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cost_object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 * )
 */
private $users;
```

and my query builder without condition

```
        $qb->select('te')
        ->from('AppBundle:TaskExecution', 'te')
        ->innerJoin('te.task', 't')

        ->leftJoin('t.costObject', 'co')
        ->leftJoin('co.users', 'com')
```

this is `$query->getSQL()`

```
SELECT some_name FROM task_executions t0_ INNER JOIN tasks t1_ ON t0_.task_id = t1_.id LEFT JOIN cost_objects c2_ ON t1_.cost_object_id = c2_.id LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers c4_ ON c2_.id = c4_.cost_object_id LEFT JOIN users u3_ ON u3_.id = c4_.user_id ORDER BY t0_.execution_start DESC
```

In this example I see `ON` relation condition `LEFT JOIN users u3_ ON u3_.id = c4_.user_id`. And need change it like in native sql

Now I have

```
        $qb->select('te')
        ->from('AppBundle:TaskExecution', 'te')
        ->innerJoin('te.task', 't')
        ->leftJoin('t.costObject', 'co')
        ->leftJoin(
            'co.users',
            'com',
            Join::ON,
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                'co = com.costObjects',
                'co.parent = com.costObjects'
            )
        )
```

but got error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 112: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'
```

if I used `WITH` condition, in my sql represent I still have relation by id, I don't need that

```
            ->leftJoin(
            'co.users',
            'com',
            Join::WITH,
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                'co MEMBER OF com.costObjects',
                'co.parent MEMBER OF com.costObjects'
            )
        )

LEFT JOIN users u3_ ON u3_.id = c4_.user_id AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cost_object_managers c5_ INNER JOIN cost_objects c6_ ON c5_.cost_object_id = c6_.id WHERE c5_.user_id = u3_.id AND c6_.id IN (c2_.id)) OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cost_object_managers c5_ INNER JOIN cost_objects c6_ ON c5_.cost_object_id = c6_.id WHERE c5_.user_id = u3_.id AND c6_.id IN (c2_.parent_id)))
```

I mean `users u3_ ON u3_.id = c4_.user_id AND` but in native query we have only `LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers AS com ON com.cost_object_id = co.id OR com.cost_object_id = co.parent_id`

How it's reproduce in Query Builder with `ON` condition type?

Comment: I used Symfony. And I need Query Builder represent

Answer (score 0):

If you have the query and it works for you, you don't need to do all the work to transform it to DQL or the QueryBuilder programmatic syntax. You can just use Doctrine's Native Query and then - if needed - map the result to your object. Just create a custom repository and in it a new method that roughly looks like this:

```
public function findTaskExecutionBy...()
{
    $query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery('SELECT te.id FROM ...');

    return $query->getSingleScalarResult(); // If it's just one id you expect
}
```

You can also use `$query->getResult()` if you expect multiple id's to be returned. Or use the ResultSetMapping if you want the whole Task-object:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->entityManager);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('App\Entity\Task', 'te');

$query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery(
    'SELECT te.* FROM ...',
```

You can also check the Doctrine documentation for a more detailed explanation and some more examples: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html
        $rsm
    );

Comment: Great good advice *If you have the query and it works for you, you don't need to do all the work to transform it to DQL*

Comment: In my case I need query builder query